# Python Pandas Dataframe manipulation (Excel File)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to Python and I have a issue with dataframe manipulation using EXCEL:

This is a snippet of the excel:

[image: Excel Snippet]

I was able to drop the duplicates for datetime rows, and get a dataframe with only the datatime rows and another with only the descriptions;

I was able to drop the last row as well:

[image: drop duplicates]

What I wanted to do is to 'shift' the column A with dates to column B for the row above.

If both Dataframes were 1-1 its easy, but I have a row (in yellow) that does not have any datetime below.

Anyone has any idea how to do it?

To be something like this>
[image]

```
    df_cdms_labour = pd.read_excel(test_cdms,
                               header=None,
                               names=['start_date', 'end_date', 'price','percent',
                                      'comment','rate',  'rate_comment','number_1','markup','markup_number'])

    df_cdms_labour.drop(df_cdms_labour.tail().index,inplace=True)
    df_cdms_labour
```

```
    def get_rate_text(df):
    return(df.loc[4,'start_date']     
    )

    def get_rates(df):
    flt = df.loc[:,'start_date'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime))
    return(df[flt]
           .drop_duplicates()
           .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
    rates = get_rates(df_cdms_labour)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sry, will do better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition using standard [**`pandas frame's`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) functions :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def flag_delete(df):
    df.insert(0, "temp_col",  df.groupby("Col_A")["Col_A"].transform("count"))
    df.loc[df.pop("temp_col").eq(1), df.columns!="Col_A"] = "DELETE"
    return df

def format_dates(df):
    temp_df = df.select_dtypes('datetime64')
    df[temp_df.columns] = temp_df.apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y'))
    return df


df= (
        pd.read_excel("BrunoA.xlsx", header=None, dtype=str)
            .assign(Col_A= lambda x: pd.Series(np.where(~x[0].str.contains("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", regex=True), x[0], np.NaN)).ffill(),
                    Col_B= lambda x: np.where(x[0].str.contains("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", regex=True), x[0], np.NaN))
            .drop(columns=0)
            .drop_duplicates()
            .apply(lambda _: pd.to_datetime(_, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors="ignore"))
            .pipe(format_dates)
            .pipe(flag_delete)
            .dropna()
            .rename(columns={"Col_A": -1, "Col_B": 0})
            .sort_index(axis=1)
            .reset_index(drop=True)
     )

display(df)
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Comment: Nice one. Will try

Comment: THis one works fone, thank you @abokey